# Cannot enable my keyboard on Kindle Fire

Tags: android, kindle, ime, kindle-fire

I've developed a keyboard app that exhibits strange behavior on Kindle Fire. Specifically, I cannot enable it.

After installing the app, I go to Settings / Language & Keyboard / Keyboard. Then I click the checkbox to enable my keyboard, and click OK on the warning. This is when it gets weird: I then click "Default" to make it the default, but it's not on the list available keyboards. When I close the dialog, the checkbox I just checked (to enable it) is unchecked!

I am using the Kindle Fire emulators but I've received reports of the same bug from users with Kindle devices. My app works fine on non-Kindle Android devices. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard selection menu was [disabled](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=TxW7NVSIV8VQ18) in the Kindle Fire.

Comment: Thanks. Funny how they didn't mention that when they APPROVED my app!